# Edit of own post comes in review queue

Tags: support, review

Just a few moments ago I was asked to review this suggested edit: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4414489

I was breaking my head thinking what was actually going on, and I wonder if this is the desired behavior of the editing system.

- OP asked a question;
- Later on he adds and accepts an answer;
- After a while he changes his answer;
- This edit come in the review queue.

I wonder why an edit of an own answer comes in the review queue. Is there a reason for this behavior?

**EDIT:**

It seems this is the same user or another user sharing the same name (is that even possible). Maybe the mods can check this out?

Comment: It's 2 different accounts (same user or not).

Comment: That's a good find of you. I only looked at the name, not the avatar. This might be a case for the mods to check.

Comment: @PatrickHofman You don't need to know whether or not it's the same person behind the account to know to reject the edit.

Comment: @Servy: I didn't even got that far. I saw the username being the same and I immediately became afraid of a review audit so I froze ;)

Comment: I see the account is now suspended for voting irregularities. That seems an answer to me.

Comment: I checked by hovering the mouse over the name to see the user id. It is the most reliable way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a different user.  It may be the same person, and they do have the same name, but the reputation is different the user profiles are different, etc.  If the user created two accounts, and this isn't a case of two different people sharing a name, they could potentially merge them.

The edit should be rejected, because it's a radical change by another user.  If this is in fact the same person behind both users, they should be making the edits with the account that authored the post.

---

After this post was written the users have since been merged, so to future readers, it will appear as if the actions were taken by only one account, when it was in fact two.