# Suggested edit by OP in the review queue?

Tags: support, review, edits, suggested-edits

I just saw [this edit](https://physics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/116372) in the Suggested Edits review queue over in Physics, and I'm rather confused as to what's going on.

[image]

The suggested edit is attributed to the OP - same username, same identicon, s̶a̶m̶e̶ ̶u̶s̶e̶r̶ ̶i̶d̶ ̶(̶t̶h̶o̶u̶g̶h̶ ̶i̶t̶ ̶s̶e̶e̶m̶s̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶h̶a̶v̶e̶ ̶k̶e̶p̶t̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶O̶P̶'̶s̶ ̶r̶e̶p̶ ̶a̶n̶d̶ ̶b̶a̶d̶g̶e̶s̶ ̶a̶t̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶t̶i̶m̶e̶ ̶o̶f̶ ̶a̶s̶k̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶o̶n̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶l̶e̶f̶t̶?̶)̶ (not actually, as it turns out - user ids 15582 and 15852 are very similar by a fluke, but not actually the same). Posters are meant to be able to edit their own posts without restriction and without their edits being sent to the review queue, right? Or does that break down in some circumstances? Alternatively, was this a bug on the handling system?

I am aware of a similar question here, [Edit of own post comes in review queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226649/edit-of-own-post-comes-in-review-queue), which blames the appearance of [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4414489) on the review queue on the fact that, at the time, the OP and editor were different accounts (which have since been merged). However, in the example above, both users had the same user id at the time of the review. If they were different accounts that were merged halfway between the edit suggestion and the review, shouldn't the edit be taken out of the queue? (Or is that too much of an edge case to be worth the trouble?)

To make things worse, here's how the [post in question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/43216/8563) looks:

[image]

And indeed b̶o̶t̶h̶ ̶a̶c̶c̶o̶u̶n̶t̶s̶ ̶l̶i̶n̶k̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶s̶a̶m̶e̶ ̶u̶s̶e̶r̶. For comparison, this is what a self-edited post looks like:

[image]

So what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That user has two accounts ([one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/15582/bob) and [two](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/15852/bob)). One of them is unregistered, which means he didn't log on before performing some actions. He did set his name though.

Those accounts should be merged. I guess it happened by accident. OP lost his credentials and thought to create a new account, or didn't notice he was logged off.

You could flag that post and ask a moderator to investigate this.

Comment: Ooooh, oh, I see, 15582 and 15852 are not actually the same user id. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: I don't think moderators can merge accounts these days, only SE team, so the user  must submit a request via the "contact us" link. (So flagging won't probably do any good)

Comment: Indeed, but I don't think OP should do that but the actual user involved. A moderator cal detect foul play and can take actions that the team doesn't have to do.  @ShadowWizard

Comment: Okay, I am ashamed. The duplicate question was my own... I really need to get my mind together and not forget about every post I have asked here... @E.P.

Comment: @Patrick No worries - I was on the lookout for precisely that behaviour, and I scoured them fives and eights and twos, but I still managed to miss the differences. Shame on me for such a dumb post, really.